# Как в Ubuntu изменить файловый менеджер по умолчанию?

Tags: linux

Как сделать, чтобы по умолчанию был не nautilus, а другой файловый менеджер?

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager) детально всё описано (правда, по-аглицки).

Comment: Спасибо, разберусь.

Answer (score 1):

Расскажу как я в Ubuntu сделал.

Для начала установил парочку файловых менеджеров (мне больше всего понравился PCManFM).

после я запустил терминал , и ввел команду где я нахожусь (не обязательная операция)

```
comp@comp0:~$ pwd
/home/comp
```

после надо перейти в директорию  /usr/share/applications

```
 cd /usr/share/applications
```

после надо в конфигурационном файле defaults.list заменить nautilus на название той программы которой вы хотите пользоваться.

Вводим

```
editor defaults.list
```

после чего поиском `^W` вводим nautilus и получаем такою строку `inode/directory=nautilus.desktop` заменяем nautilus, на  pcmanfm`inode/directory=pcmanfm.desktop` всё :3

По крайней мере у меня так, пользуюсь Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Можно удалить наутилус и поставить другой файловый мененджер,посмотри в центре приложений,от KDE-оболочки,ну не знаю мне нравилось.правда вместе с эти нужно будет удалить желательно все исполняемые файлы которые нужны для наутилуса,и поставить вместо них кдешные,помоему еще и браузер установиться с большей половиной менеджера